# API endpoint to update one to one relationship

Tags: api, api-design

I have the 2 entities, Post and PostStatus:

```
Post (PostId PK, PostStatusId FK, Title, Content)

PostStatus (PostStatusId PK, Name)
```

A `Post` has one `PostStatus`, always defined, with one of 3 values:

```
PostStatusId    Name    
1               Approved
2               OnHold
3               Rejected
```

I created an API endpoint for Posts urls as follows:

```
HTTP POST     /posts             > Create new post
HTTP PUT      /posts/{postId}    > Update post 
HTTP DELETE   /posts/{postId}    > Delete post 
HTTP GET      /posts/{postId}    > Get post
```

What would be the correct API url to update the PostStatus to one of the 3 values: `Approved`, `OnHold` and `Rejected`.

I have 2 options:

1. Update only the PostStatus.
2. Update the PostStatus but send extra data which is different depending on the PostStatus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to map resources returned by API to correspond database structure. It's even better to keep them separated, because it gives you more flexibility. For instance you may want to switch to NoSQL in future and then it probably will be single collection that holds Post and Post status. But API interface should not be changed.

With that being said, I would include status into `Post` object returned by API. Then updating status is just `PATCH` (if you want to update only status):

```
PATCH /posts/{id}
{ status: OnHold }
```

Or use `PUT` if you are replacing entire resource.